# WinCE CF2.0 control textbox IME

Tags: .net, compact-framework, ime

I am writing a smart device application for WinCE with .NET 2.0 CompactFramework. In the full 2.0 framework I can control IME (input method editor) with this.ImeMode. This property is not available on CompactFramework. Is there anything I can do like calling something from a wince DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [InputPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y4s0819%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You can [iterate the existing InputMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel.inputmethods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as well as [set the current one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel.currentinputmethod%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).